# Reset google autocomplete input value after select a location with VueJs

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I need to clean up the google autocomplete input after select a location. I assigned a data value to the value prop of the component but seems like it doesn't change. Even using a watch, seem's like nothing happens.

This is my InputPlace component:

```
<template>
  <label class="form-label-place" for="city">
    <input class="form-control pr-5" :value="value" type="text" id="inputPlace" name="city" placeholder="Ingresa tu ciudad">
  </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'input-place',
  props: {
    value: ''
  },
  mounted() {
      // Google autocomplete
      const options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: "PE"}
      };

      const places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('inputPlace'), options);
      google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', () => {
        this.$parent.placeChanged(places)
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is how i'm using it into the view:

```
<template>
  ...
  <input-place :value="InputPlaceValue"></input-place>
</template>
<script>
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      activePlaces: [],
      InputPlaceValue: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    placeChanged(places) {
       let placeName = places.getPlace().name;

       if(!this.activePlaces.includes(placeName)) this.activePlaces.push(placeName)
       this.InputPlaceValue = ''
    }
  }
</script>
```

Hope you can help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to clear autocomplete text field would be to:

a) use `v-model` directive

```
<input v-model="selectedAddress" class="form-control pr-5" type="text" id="inputPlace" name="city" placeholder="Ingresa tu ciudad">
```

b) and clear input value once `place_changed` event is triggered like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(places, "place_changed", () => {
  this.selectedAddress = "";
});
```

**`InputPlace.vue` example**

```
<template>
  <label class="form-label-place" for="city">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputPlace" v-model="selectedAddress" name="city" placeholder="Search..">
  </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  /* global google */
  name: "input-place",
  data () {
    return {
      selectedAddress: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const options = {
      types: ["(cities)"]
    };
    const places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("inputPlace"),
      options
    );
    google.maps.event.addListener(places, "place_changed", () => {
      this.selectedAddress = "";
      this.$parent.placeChanged(places)
    });
  }
};
</script>
```